# How to merge multiple query from single table?

Tags: sql-server

How to merge multiple query from single table?
this is my current query, but the output is wrong

```
   SELECT     
        Employees201MasterFile.Name, CASE WHEN SUM(StockTrans.conv_bal) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(StockTrans.conv_bal) END AS 'curMonthBal',
        CASE WHEN SUM(StockTrans.conv_bal) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(StockTrans.conv_bal) END AS 'prevMonthsBal'
   FROM 
        Employees201MasterFile INNER JOIN
        Stocktrans ON Employees201MasterFile.Name = Stocktrans.Customer
   WHERE
        stocktrans.date >= '12/01/15' AND stocktrans.date <= '12/31/15'
        OR stocktrans.date < '12/01/15' AND stocktrans.conv_bal <> 0
   GROUP BY Employees201MasterFile.Name
---------------------------------------------------------------
name    currentMonthBalance   prevMonBal
EMP1    114                   114           
EMP2    182                   182   
EMP3    29                    29
```

the output should be

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
name    currentMonthBalance   prevMonBal
EMP1    114                   366           
EMP2    0                     182           
EMP3    29                    0
```

My desired output:
pseudo query:

```
if employee has balance on this month (december 1 - 31, 2015 only), sum all balance for this month ELSE return 0
--> this will be the currentMonthBalance

if employee has previous month balance, sum all previous balance except (december 2015) the selected month ELSE return 0
--> this will be the prevBalance
```

is this possible on SQL Query?

Comment: Is `PrevMonBal` equals to all balance before Dec 1, 2015? Or just Nov 1 2015 to Nov 30 2015?

Comment: yes sir, it is the summation of all balance before the selected month (Dec 1, 2015) in the example. regardless of the year. even last year balances will be computed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thy this query:

```
SELECT x.Name, curMonthBal, prevMonthsBal FROM
(
   SELECT     
        Employees201MasterFile.Name, CASE WHEN SUM(StockTrans.conv_bal) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(StockTrans.conv_bal) END AS 'curMonthBal'
   FROM 
        Employees201MasterFile INNER JOIN
        Stocktrans ON Employees201MasterFile.Name = Stocktrans.Customer
   WHERE
        stocktrans.date >= '12/01/15' AND stocktrans.date <= '12/31/15'
        AND stocktrans.conv_bal <> 0
   GROUP BY Employees201MasterFile.Name
) x
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT     
        Employees201MasterFile.Name,
        CASE WHEN SUM(StockTrans.conv_bal) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(StockTrans.conv_bal) END AS 'prevMonthsBal'
   FROM 
        Employees201MasterFile INNER JOIN
        Stocktrans ON Employees201MasterFile.Name = Stocktrans.Customer
   WHERE
        stocktrans.date < '12/01/15' AND stocktrans.conv_bal <> 0
   GROUP BY Employees201MasterFile.Name
) y
ON  x.Name = y.Name
```

Comment: from your suggested answer I modify it and solves my problem thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
DECLARE @fromMonth AS DATE = '20151201'

SELECT     
    emf.Name, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN st.date >= @fromMonth AND st.date < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @fromMonth) THEN st.conv_val ELSE 0 END) AS [curMonthBal],
    SUM(CASE WHEN st.date < @fromMonth THEN st.conv_val ELSE 0 END) AS [prevMonthsBal]
FROM Employees201MasterFile AS emf
INNER JOIN Stocktrans AS st
    ON emf.Name = st.Customer
WHERE
    st.date < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @fromMonth)
GROUP BY emf.Name
```

*You should use a meaningful alias on your tables for easier readability.*